# Implement 2d array coordinates in 1d array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

The code inside the for loop is for the x and y (j and i) "coordinates" from a 2d array. How could I implement this neighbor/index finding in a 1d array?
I think I could implement it for the first four equations. But i'm confused as how to implement up-left etc.

```
for(int i=0; i<cols*rows; i++){
        //Counts current index's 8 neigbour int values
      int count=0;
      int x = i%cols;
      int y = i/rows;
      //rows y i
      //cols x j

      count+= [grid][i][(j-1+cols)%cols] //left
         +[grid][i][(j+1+cols)%cols]    //right
         +[grid][(i-1+rows)%rows][j]    //up
         +[grid][(i+1+rows)%rows][j]    //down
         +[grid][(i-1+rows)%rows][ (j-1+cols)%cols]  //up-left
         +[grid][(i+1+rows)%rows][ (j+1+cols)%cols]  //down-right
         +[grid][(i+1+rows)%rows][ (j-1+cols)%cols]  //down-left
         +[grid][(i-1+rows)%rows][ (j+1+cols)%cols] ;//up-right
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you have a 1D array, example `int grid[rows * cols]`? You have calculated `x`/`y` where data should be `grid[i]`

Comment: Yes, the size of my 1d array is rows*cols. I have a 1d array, but the neighbor finding is for a 2d array I want to know how to do this equation(s) for a 1d array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with a 1-D vector:

```
int rows = 10;
int cols = 10;
vector<int> grid(rows * cols);
```

You can manage this in different ways, example

```
for(int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
    {
        int point = grid[y * rows + x];
    }
}
```

Where you can access any point at any given `x` and `y` in a 2-dimensional plane.

Top-left is:

```
x = 0;
y = 0;
```

bottom-right is

```
x = cols - 1;
y = rows - 1;
```

And so on.

Comment: Could you get the coordinates (x,y) from the index of the loop without making more for loops?

Comment: If you know the index `i`, then `x = i%cols` and `y = i/rows`, you already did that yourself! Conversely, if you know `x` and `y`, then index is `i = y * rows + x` as shown above.

Comment: That's not quite right to get from index to x, y. It should be `x = i%cols` and `y = i/cols`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a function like this

```
inline int idx(const int i, const int j, const int rows) const
{
    return i * rows + j;
}
```

to convert the 2d indices to 1d indices.
This way you don't have to change your algorithm.

Usage would be `grid[idx(i, (j-1+cols)%cols, rows)]`.

Answer (score 0):

The basic formula for computing the 1d coordinate from the 2d index pattern is usually one of the following:

- `row_index * row_length + column_index`
- `column_index * column_length + row_index`

Which one applies to your case depends on whether you would like to have a [row-based or column-based memory layout for your 2d array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order). It makes sense to factor out the computation of this index into a separate function, [as suggested in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49125001/1025391).

Then you just need to fill in the values somehow.

You could do it like this, for example:

```
// iterate big picture
// TODO: make sure to handle the edge cases appropriately
for (int i_row = 1; i_row < n_rows - 1; i_row++) {
    for (int i_col = 1; i_col < n_cols -1; i_col++) {
        // compute values
        dst[i_row*n_cols+i_col] = 0;
        for (int r = i_row-1; r < i_row+2; r++) {
            for (int c = i_col-1; c < i_col+2; c++) {
                dst[i_row*n_cols+i_col] += src[r*n_cols + c];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming `src` and `dst` are distinct 1d vectors of size `n_rows*n_cols`...